Static images not being included in R/exams output
I'm trying to generate Moodle exercises within R using the exams package, and am trying to include some static images in my exercises with the help of the exams package's include_supplement function. At the moment, I can't get my images to be included in either the resulting Moodle XML file or the HTML file generated by the exams2moodle and exams2html functions.
Below is a MWE Rmd file for my exercises with static images included.
``` {r}
exams::include_supplement("Saving R Script File.png",
  dir="C:/Users/fowal44p/OneDrive - University of Otago/0OLAF Transition/R-Exams/STAT110 and STAT115 questions/STAT110 2025/A1 and Lab 1/Q2")
```

Question
============
Trying to get the image to appear using markdown syntax

![Caption](Saving R Script File.png)

Answerlist
--------------
* Enter the number 1

Meta-information
=====================
extype: num
exsolution: 1
extol:0
extitle:A test qn

In exams2pdf the image is included correctly but not it exams2html or exams2moodle. Instead the caption is displayed twice.

Note that the static image I want to include is in the same folder as the question Rmd file.

If include_supplement returns FALSE,  then it cannot find the  specified graphic in the directory. Maybe it is named slightly differently or something like that? Additionally: For num questions there should not be an answerlist.

Thanks @AchimZeileis. include_supplement is returning TRUE now, but the same issue remains of the image not appearing. In terms of whether it's a mispelling of the file name, it seems odd because the markdown command to insert the image (![Caption](Saving R Script File.png)) works with exams2pdf (the image gets included in the output pdf), but not with exams2moodle and exams2html. So if it was a mispelling then the image wouldn't be included in exams2pdf's output either. Any other ideas?

It also appears like the caption is being planted in where the image should be in exams2moodle and exams2html's output. See the screenshot of the html file in the post itself, the two "Caption"s appear on top of one another. The top "Caption" is not highlightable while the bottom one is - indicating that the top Caption is an image, while the bottom is the Caption text.

The fact that "Caption" is shown twice is due to the figure not being available. It is shown once as the "Caption" and once as the alt text for the missing figure. My guess is that either the original figure is not available (e.g., because file or path are called slightly differently) - or the supplementary copy cannot be created (e.g., due to limited rights in the temporary directory).

For checking the availability of the original graphic, use: file.exists(file.path("C:/Users/fowal44p/OneDrive - University of Otago/0OLAF Transition/R-Exams/STAT110 and STAT115 questions/STAT110 2025/A1 and Lab 1/Q2", "Saving R Script File.png"))
For using a different temporary directory use exams2html(..., tdir = "C:/.../path/to/my/folder")
Important: For tdir use a directory that is really empty and does not contain any file/folder that you want to preserve. The temporary directories are wiped eventually.

Many thanks for the reply @Achim. I've tried those things and have added my reply to the bottom of the original post (below "UPDATE TO POST FOLLOWING DISCUSSION IN COMMENTS:") My reply was long and included images so it didn't suit to put the reply in the comments. Hope that this can be fixed!

Note: When this gets resolved, I'll update the post and post an answer so that people can use this if they get the same issue in the future.

Thanks for the additional explanations. With that I was able to track down what happens: The culprit are the spaces in the graphics file name which are encoded as %20 by some HTML converters but not by others. I would recommend to avoid these. I'll modify the question correspondingly and post an answer.

Source of the problem:
The problem is due to the spaces in the file name Saving R Script File.png of your static image. Some of the HTML converters employed in R/exams preserve these as they are while others encode them as Saving%20R%20Script%20File.png. In the latter case the code that prepares everything for the output format does not recognize that this is in fact the same as the original file name. Hence the image is not correctly embedded into the HTML output.
Workaround:
As the code that does the embedding does not know anymore which converter was used, it is best to avoid the problem by using file names without spaces. So the easiest solution would be to rename the original static file. If that is not easy to do, then use include_supplement(..., target = "...") to just rename the copy in the exercise.
Example:
In the Rmd from your MWE you could do:
``` {r, include=FALSE}
exams::include_supplement("Saving R Script File.png", target = "image.png")
```

Question
========
Trying to get the image to appear using markdown syntax

![](image.png)

Enter the number 1

Meta-information
================
extype: num
exsolution: 1
extol: 0
extitle: A test qn

In addition to the renaming of the image file I have done the following:

Omitted the include_supplement(..., dir = "...") argument because you mentioned that this is the same directory in which the Rmd itself is stored.
Omit the Answerlist because that is not needed/used in a num exercise.
Improve layout/spacing of markup a bit.


Great, thanks so much Achim! Should we remove the spaces in the names of any files that we want to be included in each question, or just the ones not generated within the exercise's rmd/rnw file that need to be included using include_supplement?
